# Going from dual bowl sink to single bowl

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink

[image]I am going from an old dual bowl sink, which contained a garbage disposal which I am trashing, to a single bowl sink.

I have a Y pvc splitter glued to the waste line. Is there a way to cap off one of the ends of the splitter?

With the one remaining open port I was planning on purchasing a new p-trap and straight pipe with dishwasher runoff plugin to attach to the new sink.

Am I missing anything in connecting to a new sink? Do I need to have a plumber come and remove the Y-splitter and start with a fresh connection to the waste line?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not call a plumber. I would see if I could get a plug fitting for the slip joint nearest the Y and remove the left hand branch (no cutting or gluing). This frees up space under the sink. **EDIT** I couldn't find what I was thinking of, but there must be some fittings that would seal the 1 1/2" drain pipe.

You would connect what appears to be the dishwasher drain to a special tailpiece designed for DW connection above the trap on the right side.
DW tailpiece, e.g.,  http://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-1-2-in-x-8-in-Plastic-Dishwasher-Wye-Tailpiece-C9816/205153966 or get a longer one if needed: [Watts long DW tailpiece](http://www.simplyplumbing.com/34187-dishwasher-branch-tailpiece.html?gclid=Cj0KEQjw2-bHBRDEh6qk5b6yqKIBEiQAFUz29r_7jBMUXcjsdhuDDN8JAaS-4GjvsdiAMa4nytg9L7QaAmEl8P8HAQ)

Answer (score 0):

Everything u mentioned is all there In refrence to what Jim said he is completely correct but my oppinion for $15 literally... u cut the old trap and replace it with a new one and and with the brand new one it will have a bib connect for the dishwasher hose to connect to, it's actually extremely straight forward plumbing and in the end u will have a lot more room under the sink and even the Indra of using the 1.5" remains drain don't get me wrong that could potentially work but you will still need the adapter piece for the dishwasher drain to clamp to

All in all it's cheaper less stress and more effecting to cancel the remaking drain all together and start a new trap for a single sink at the 45* right before the TY